# How to show action bar with this project

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar

I cloned a application from github but it doesn't show Action Bar. I tried everything but i can't show action bar.

Github link: https://github.com/akhgupta/WebviewVideo

How I can show status bar?

Comment: so you expect us to go clone that project and check? sir please what i know about stackoverflow is they help specific programming problems not how to make a project suits your needs, also if you want you can go ask the developer, its best that way, so i will have to vote to close. sorry sir